# Special key sequence to run cmd at Windows lock screen

Tags: windows-7

I'm aware of the hack where you can copy `cmd.exe` to the program that launches the sticky keys GUI, thereby giving you command line admin access from the Windows lock screen after pressing Shift five times.

I'm curious if there's a similar way to add a different key sequence to launch `cmd.exe` from the Windows lock screen using a different key sequence. This would allow an easier and quicker method of resetting a user's password, remoting into another machine, changing a text file without having to log in, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Ubuntu Live CD to make the Ease of Access Center shortcut (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) open `CMD` instead. Under `/Windows/System32`, rename `Utilman.exe` to something else and rename/copy+rename `CMD.exe` to `Utilman.exe`.

This will let you open `CMD` by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, and it will work everywhere.

Comment: Win+U is still a little too easy to accidentally press. I've published some internal documentation about windows shortcut keys and people may press that expecting to get the ease of access utility. I'm looking for something very obscure like alternating shift, control, alt, maybe a function key, etc. Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: @user38537 Well, you'd need another program to replace.

Answer (score 1):

You can change any `.exe` (narrator, sticky keys, magnifier)that is avaiable from a locked windows box.

I'll show you how to change the `magnify.exe`

You can change the `magnify.exe` hotkey (`Winkey` and `+`) so it will use cmd.exe with the built-in `system` account.

1. You can do this with a Windows setup Media. Just download the appropriate `ISO` file, insert and reboot.
2. When rebooting, press a key to access the installation.
3. Choose to **repair** the computer, and press `Shift+F10' to open a command prompt.
4. Look for the drive where Windows is installed on, by pressing `C:`, `D:` etc.
5. When the drive is found, browse to the System32 directory by typing `cd windows\system32`
6. First make a back-up of the `magnify.exe` in the `C:\Windows` directory, by typing `copy magnify.exe ..`
7. Now overwrite `cmd.exe` with `magnify.exe` with the following command `Copy cmd.exe magnify.exe`
8. Finally reboot the machine. and press the hotkey `WindowsKey` and `+` at the locked Windows screen to launch `cmd.exe` as the `system` account. (ability to enable/disable admin account, create new admin accounts etc.)

[image]

9. To revert the `Magnify.exe` hotkey, run the following command from an elevated command prompt. `Robocopy C:\Windows C:\Windows\System32 magnify.exe /B`
10. Now when locking again, and hitting the hotkey, you get the good old magnifier tool again:
    [image]

Comment: I'm aware of that trick. What i want is to create an entirely new key sequence, one that is undocumented on the Internet and highly unlikely the user will guess at the unlock screen, then assign an EXE to the new key sequence.