# Can I install any Windows 11 driver from Windows lock screen?

Tags: wifi-driver, lock-screen, windows-11-v22h2

Is it possible to perform manual installation of any driver while staying in lock screen in Windows 11 or a full access to the system is required in this case?

[I have restored my system from an image to a different hardware](https://superuser.com/q/1825745/156554). This caused my PIN to be locked with *Your PIN is no longer available* message and a *Setup new PIN* button. This functionality requires an active Internet access and logging into Microsoft account.

The underlying Windows 11 (restored from image) does not have drivers for wireless or wired network cards installed. For some reason in only managed to install audio card's driver. But failed with graphics card's driver or Wi-Fi or Ethernet card's driver.

I the effect, I am without any kind of Internet connection available, and cannot reset my PIN, because this requires that I have access to the Internet.

Comment: Do you use a Microsoft account and do you have its password? See Method 1 in [this link](https://10scopes.com/fix-your-pin-is-no-longer-available-on-windows-11/).

Comment: Why can’t you use the password then, reconfigure the pin, internet access isn’t required to do this

Comment: Cloning a Windows drive from one machine and using it on another is likely to fail due to driver issues, as you describe, and the copy *would not be licensed*, and cease to fully function after a while, if drivers were to be installed. Install Win  11 from ISO.

Comment: @harrymc As explained in my linked question (3rd point) using password is not possible in my case, because neither "I forgot my PIN" nor "Sign-in options" button is available. I don't know, if this is normal in W1123H2 or happens just in my case only, but "Set up my PIN" is **the only** button that I see in my lock screen.

Comment: You should be able to boot into Safe mode like is described in https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/how-to-fix-something-happened-and-your-pin-isnt-available-error-in-windows/

Comment: @harrymc As explained in my linked question (6th point), booting into Safe Mode brings absolutely no resolution in this scenario. Neither login is possible (Windows 11 even in Safe Mode requires valid PIN) nor booting into Safe Mode with Networking enabled Internet access or installs network card's driver. Also, please note, that you are trying to solve a different problem than I am asking here. I want to know how to install driver from lock screen not how to unlock my PIN. This is a topic in my second question here.

Comment: @John I have upvoted your comment, but you are generally wrong. This is possible. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1825769/156554).

Comment: You can enable the built-in Administrator and login into that account and install any required drivers.

Comment: Answer : *You cannot install anything from the Lock screen*, but it's pretty easy from Safe mode, built-in administrator login, boot media and others. I have no idea why you're obsessed with the Lock screen.

Comment: @harrymc As stated in linked question, I am locked with the need to create new PIN, but cannot accomplish this due to not having network card drivers installed. I cannot neither enable administrator login (doesn't work, I am still required to create PIN) nor by-pass Safe Mode (still requires PIN to be created). I don't understand why people around here (and my linked other questions) keeps repeating that I can do this in Safe Mode, if I have provided that in my scenario, for some reason even Safe Mode requires me to create a PIN and hence to have access to Internet.

Comment: Plus: Even if any of your listed mode would be really available in my case, that is not a part of this question! Why you are obsessed with solutions on gaining access to Windows, if question deals about installing drivers from lock screen? Somebody would like to do this just because. So both question and answer still have a value. Are you 100% sure that Stack Exchange is about simplest methods only? Or about any solution that works? If someone will be asking you about how to get from Washington to New Your by bike, will you call him obsessed only because taking train or taxi is easier?

Comment: I'm not going to stick around, just saying that no one who has physical access to a computer can be locked out of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but involves a little trick.

#### Get your driver

In order to make this solution work you must have **not compressed** driver:

1. Download .zip or .cab file, if your hardware vendor provides such
2. Download .exe file, if your vendor provides drivers in this form only.
3. Unzip downloaded file

For .zip files you can use any software that supports these files or even better Windows itself (which treats .zip files as folders). For .cab or .exe file, use Total Commander (press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>).

Source: [Add drivers manually to USB drive to install Windows using a USB 3.0 Port](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/125921-how-to-add-drivers-manually-to-usb-drive-to-install-windows-using-a-usb-3-0-port)

#### Copy driver

1. Copy your unpacked driver files, with all folders and subfolders and with (the most important) .inf file to some removable media like USB stick.
2. Put your stick to a computer where you want to install drivers from the lock screen.

#### Hack your Windows

1. Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click on Power →  Restart to boot into Recovery Mode.
2. Click on Troubleshoot → Command Prompt
3. Execute the following:

   ```bash
   cd c:\Windows\System32
   ren utilman.exe utilman.old
   ren cmd.exe utilman.exe
   ```
4. Restart computer

Alternatively you can rename `magnify.exe` to something else and then rename `cmd.exe` to `magnify.exe`.

Adjust path, if needed, but usually your Windows is installed to *c:\* drive.

Source: [Special key sequence to run cmd at Windows lock screen](https://superuser.com/a/901659/156554)

#### Access command-line from lock screen

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or
2. Click *Ease of Access Center* icon in the bottom right corner

Alternatively you can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to run <s>Magnify</s> command-line.

Source: [Special key sequence to run cmd at Windows lock screen](https://superuser.com/a/901659/156554)

#### Install driver

1. Find your USB's drive letter. You can use [`wmic`](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/list-drives-using-command-prompt-powershell-windows). Or simply iterate drives.
2. Navigate to that drive (i.e. `cd d:\` etc.)
3. Install all drivers found in this drive:

   ```bash
   pnputil /add-driver d:\*.inf /subdirs /install /reboot
   ```
4. Restart computer

Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-command-syntax) if you need more specific command's parameters for `pnputil` command.

Source: [How to install or update Drivers using Command Prompt in Windows 11/10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/update-drivers-using-command-prompt)

#### Un-hack your Windows

Access command line either directly or as described in 3rd part and execute the following:

```bash
cd c:\Windows\System32
ren utilman.exe cmd.exe
ren utilman.old utilman.exe
```

You should be done.

Comment: Simpler methods than this were proposed in the comments, but the poster insists on the Lock screen.

Comment: @harrymc As stated in question, I am locked and need to create new PIN, but cannot do this without installing network card drivers from lock screen. I cannot neither enable administrator login (doesn't work, I am still required to create PIN) nor by-pass Safe Mode (still requires PIN to be created). Your claim is false the described (in this answer) solution is the only that works. The only other working is given in linked question -- using Android phone and USB tethering. None of your (or others) listed methods (admin account, Safe Mode) are working. Tested and explained. Many times.

Comment: If you still insist that any of your methods really works then explain this or provide evidences.